# catch error while fire and forget inside useEffect hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm very new to react I'm experimenting with the use-effect hook
I'm trying to call and async function inside use effect
something like this :

```
useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
       await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
       console.log("done"); 
       throw new error("error in here"); 
    }
    try {
   
      fetchData(); 
    
    }
    catch(error){
        console.log("error catching",error); 
    }
  });
```

is this code the catch will not work since useEffect will return before fetchData

i'm aware that adding  `fetchData().catch(error => {console.log("error catched")});`

will resolve the problem.

is this a correct solution or can i do better  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The React `useEffect` hook does not support `async`/`await`. So you can't use a traditional `try`/`catch` as this is only supported for async/await style syntax. You'll need to use it like this:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
       await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
       console.log("done"); 
       throw new error("error in here"); 
    }

   
      fetchData().catch(err => {
          console.log("error catching",error); 
       });
    

  });
```

Comment: why `useEffect` doesn't support `try/catch`?

Comment: Because it doesn't? Ask Facebook.

Comment: That is normal question, so people get the knowledge why we don't use. If we are allowed to ask Facebook then everyone asking the same question to Facebook instead here.

Comment: Well I don't know why it doesn't support it, so I'm not sure what you want me to say. I didn't write react facebook did, for some (likely very good reason) it does not support async await, just traditional promises `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: @sushildlh, `useEffect` callbacks are executed synchronously. Remember that, you can return a function in `useEffect` callback. React will call that function, when it unmounts the component. So, if you want to use `try/catch`, the you have to make the callback `async`. When you do that, the callback returns a promise, instead of any value that you might return. In your case, you are not returning anything from the callback, so you can make it async and use `try/catch`. Simply prefix `await` before the `fetchData` call. It would work. Or you can write a async function with try catch block

Comment: ...and call that from the `useEffect` callback. Previously it did not worked because, you did not awaited, when you called `fetchData`

Answer (score 0):

`useEffect` callbacks are executed synchronously. Remember that, you can return a function in `useEffect` callback. React will call that function, when it unmounts the component. So, if you want to use `try/catch`, the you have to make the callback `async`. When you do that, the callback returns a promise, instead of any value that you might return. In your case, you are not returning anything from the callback, so you can make it async and use `try/catch`. Simply prefix `await` before the `fetchData` call. It would work. Or you can write a async function with try catch block and call that from the `useEffect` callback. Previously it did not worked because, you did not awaited, when you called `fetchData`

The following things would work. In both scenarios, notice the `await` keyword.

```
useEffect(async () => {
    async function fetchData() {
       await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
       console.log("done"); 
       throw new error("error in here"); 
    }
    try {
   
      await fetchData(); 
    
    }
    catch(error){
        console.log("error catching",error); 
    }
  });
```

```
  useEffect(() => {
    loadData();
  });

    async function fetchData() {
       await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
       console.log("done"); 
       throw new error("error in here"); 
    }
    
    async function loadData() {
      
      try {
 
        await fetchData(); 
   
      }
      catch(error){
        console.log("error catching",error); 
      }

    }
```